# Mapping a pair of python string in a list based on a text similarity score

Tags: python, string, mapping

Can someone kindly help me out on this? I have two lists of strings which may not be of the same length. I need to map a string in list 'A' to one and only one string in list 'B' using the maximum score of a text similarity method either cosine jacckard similarity.

Example is as follows:

```
A = ['I love in eating apple every Tuesday','I went to the bank to withdraw money','Is python a snake or a programming language']
B = ['Apple is good for your health, endeavour to eat one once a week', 'I bank with North-West bank located at apple street where I withdraw money every time','Python programming is interesting','I am a good chef and eating is my hobby']
```

What I want is a result as follows:

```
{'I love in eating apple every Tuesday':'Apple is good for your health, endeavor to eat one once a week',I went to the bank to withdraw money':I bank with North-West bank located at apple street where I withdraw money every time','Is python a snake or a programming language':'Python programming is interesting'}
```

Notice that when the length is different, the string with least matching word is not matched.

Thanks.

@Megalng What am saying is that the mapping was not done based on overlapping words in the matched strings.

```
import re, math
from collections import Counter

def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection]) 
    sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)
    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator

def vector(text):
    return Counter(text)                                                                                                          result = {}
for s1 in A:

    s2 = max(B, key=lambda x:cosine_sim(vector(s1),vector(x)))
    B.remove(s2)
    result[s1] = s2
print(result)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Megalng. I can compute the similarity score using either cosine of jaccard but the only problem am having is how to map the strings in list A to exactly one string in List B.

Comment: So you have a function which returns a number which represents the similarity of two strings?

Comment: exactly! Which means if a string in B is already matched to a string in A, another be cannot be matched to that string in A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a function `similarity(s1, s2)` which returns a number?
If this is the case, you should be able to do something like this:

```
A = ['I love in eating apple every Tuesday', 'I went to the bank to withdraw money', 'Is python a snake or a programming language']
B = ['Apple is good for your health, endeavor to eat one once a week', 'I bank with North-West bank located at apple street where I withdraw money every time',
     'Python programming is interesting', 'I am a good chef and eating is my hobby']
result = {}
for s1 in A:
    s2 = max(B, key=lambda x:similarity(s1,x))
    B.remove(s2)
    result[s1] = s2
print(result)
```

Comment: I noticed that the strings got mapped not taking into account the similarity function. What's wrong?

Comment: @Alex That is something I implemented with the line `B.remove(s2)`. If you do want to reuse the strings from B, just remove this line.

Comment: @Alex what do you mean by 'based on overlapping words'?

Comment: @Megalng The mapping is not being done based on the number of words that appear in the strings to be matched which is the reason am using cosine similarity. I tried this on this samples list above and larger lists

Comment: @Alex If this yields wrong outputs, you have to change the similarity function

Comment: @Alex You can also try to change your vector function to be case-insensitive and ignore spaces: `Counter(text.lower().replace(" ",""))`

Comment: @Megalng Thanks